# jq grab keys from array of objects

Tags: jq

Let's say I have the following array:

```json
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
    "d": 4
  },
  {
    "a": 10,
    "b": 20,
    "c": 30,
    "d": 40
  },
  {
    "a": 100,
    "b": 200,
    "c": 300,
    "d": 400
  }
]
```

I want to generate a new array with just the `a` and `b` keys. I know I can do it like this:

```
ARRAY | jq '. | map({ a: .a, b: .b })'
```

I'm not renaming any of the keys so having to type `a` and `b` seems a bit verbose. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to type `a` and `b` once in order to specify which ones to keep:

```bash
jq 'map({a,b})'
```

Alternatively, specify what to delete, here `.c` and `.d`:

```bash
jq 'map(del(.c,.d))'
```

In any case, `.|` is also superfluous.